# Is it possible to access the event object in a function without having to pass it in?

Tags: javascript, closures

So i have this `equalizer` function here, which gives all elements the same minHeight. **The function uses lodash's throttle function and executes everytime the window resizes and on load**.

```
export const equalizer = throttle((elems, e, stopAt = 0) => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(elems)];

  const setMinHeight = (el) => el.style.minHeight = '0px';

  if (e.type === 'resize') elements.forEach(setMinHeight);

  const minHeight = elements.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.clientHeight >= acc) return cur.clientHeight;
    if (acc >= cur.clientHeight) return acc;
  }, 0);

  elements.forEach((el) => (el.style.minHeight = `${minHeight}px`));

}, 500);
```

So the "problem" now is that everytime I call this function I have to pass in the `event object` (because of `e.type === "resize"` ) and I want to know if there is a way to avoid that.

```
['load', 'resize'].forEach((event) => {
  window.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
    equalizer('.comment__body p', e);
    equalizer('.comment__header .comment__name', e);
  });
});
```

I thought that I don't even need to pass in the event object because of closures. And the way I understand closures is that a function has access to it's outer functions variables.

**So is there a way to access the `event object` in this `equalizer` function without me having to everytime passing it in?**

Comment: No. `e` is a parameter of that function, so you must pass it as an argument. Also no, that's not how closures work, your `equalizer` is not declared within the scope where `e` is available, so it's not quite clear what you mean by "outer function".

Comment: Oh okey. I guess I had a missunderstanding of how closures work. Thank you :)